# Delete unpublished woocommerce products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have 1000s of unpublished products on my woocommerce store. I would like to delete all these products and remove the entries from the database.

Can someone suggest me a way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your unpublished product is concept ? if it is yes, then you have a tab at Products page in admin page above products table "All | Published | Concept | Trashed"

You can filter products by click to "Concept" and select all product and delete all.
If you want delete everything at once, you must set number of result products on top of product admin page called "Display options" and result on page "1000"

Comment: Thank you for the reply. this is all good. But the database still saves some information even after the products are deleted. Do you know a way to remove these from the database as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is a code. Your unpublished products must be a "Draft"
and you must join in DB mysql, and click to tab "SQL"

And paste this code -> "ztzpzu" is my wp preffix. Your prefix and login to DB find in wp-config.php in root of wordpress FTP

```
DELETE relations.*, taxes.*, terms.*
FROM ztzpzu_term_relationships AS relations
INNER JOIN ztzpzu_term_taxonomy AS taxes
ON relations.term_taxonomy_id=taxes.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN ztzpzu_terms AS terms
ON taxes.term_id=terms.term_id
WHERE object_id IN (SELECT ID FROM ztzpzu_posts WHERE post_status='draft' AND post_type='product');
  
DELETE FROM ztzpzu_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (SELECT ID FROM ztzpzu_posts WHERE post_status='draft' AND post_type='product');
DELETE FROM ztzpzu_posts WHERE post_status='draft' AND post_type='product';
```